# Mod Rewrite to create a short direct link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently on my website visitors can directly access different posts by going to "www.mywebsite.com/index.php?post=123", where 123 is the post number.

I am trying to use htaccess to clean up the direct link up slightly, the desired result is that the user can go to "www.mywebsite.com/123" and htaccess will take them to "www.mywebsite.com/index.php?post=123.

I have tried using the following Modrewrite but it is directing me to a 404 error:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?videoID=$1 [QSA]
```

I am sure that the Modrewrite module is working because I am using other rules aswell. Here is my entire .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?videoID=$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try the [R] option at that rewrite to see how actually redirects are happening.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Shubham, when I add [R] nothing changes. What should I be looking for?

Comment: http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html: See the "forcing new request" part.

Comment: Understood. Initially, even with [R] the page still wasn't moving. It looks like I had the forward slashes mixed up though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these rules are in your .htaccess file, you need to remove the prefix (the leading slash) from the regular expression used to match against the URI:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.php?videoID=$1 [QSA]
```